# awesome-wm polkit authentication agent?

Tags: awesome-wm, polkit

## Polkit authentication agent on awesome-wm?

I have problems when opening balenaEtcher for usb-flashing.
It instantly gives me an error saying:
"No polkit authentication agent found"

My questions now is, which polkit-aa should be installed when using awesome-wm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Manjaro, I use polkit-gnome and have this in my rc.lua under my startup programs...

"/usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 &"

works well. And I have used Etcher with it and get the login dialog.